# Importing into sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to import a pipe(|) separated .txt file into a sqlite database without creating duplicate rows. Essentially I would like to always use the same file to import data into the sqlite database however, I only want it to import the new/unique elements within that file to the database.

I am using sqlite3 from the command line.

Comment: Please provide sample data, schema and the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disallow duplicates, use a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint on the column(s) that identify the rows. To prevent errors when the duplicates are tried to be inserted, put an [ON CONFLICT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) on the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    X TEXT,
    Y TEXT,
    Z TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (X, y) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
```